# Continuity of operations in topological groups

Tags: topological-groups

I have a question regarding continuity in topological groups. From Wikipedia:

A topological group $G$ is a topological space that is also a group such that the group operation:

\begin{align*}
\mu: G \times G &\rightarrow G\\
(x,y) & \mapsto xy
\end{align*}

and inversion map:

\begin{align*}
\iota: G &\rightarrow G\\
x & \mapsto x^{-1}
\end{align*}

are continuous. The product map is continuous iff for any $x,y \in G$ and any neighborhood $W$ of $xy$ in $G$, there exist neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ in $G$ such that $U\cdot V \subseteq W$.

Now what bothers me is that the real definition of continuity for this operation should be:

The product map is continuous iff for any $x,y \in G$ and any neighborhood $W$ of $xy$ in $G$, there exists a neighborhood $U\times V$ of $(x,y)$ in $G \times G$ such that $U\times V \subseteq \mu^{-1}(W)$.

Why is not this the definition? Is there some "trivial" way to go from one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Note that $U \cdot V \subseteq W$ is the same as saying that $\mu(U \times V) \subseteq W$.  This is indeed equivalent to $U \times V \subseteq \mu^{-1}(W)$.

Indeed, $f(X) \subseteq Y$ and $X \subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$ are equivalent statements in general for any function $f$, just by unpacking the definition of an inverse function.

Comment: I see. Now it's clear. I can't never seem to get those set theory identities right. Thank you very much.